# Roots of $f(x)=x-2+\frac{a-3}{x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, roots

I wanted to find the values of (a) for which the function $f(x)=x-2+\frac{a-3}{x}$ has more than one root.

I know that the equation needs to be set equal to zero, from that step onward I have no idea how to proceed:

$$x-2+\frac{a-3}{x}=0$$
$$x^{2}-2x+a-3=0$$

from this point forward.

Comment: Hint:  How do you find the roots of a quadratic equation?

Comment: Keep in mind that a is a constant (if I understood correctly). Thus, Use the quadratic formula for root finding with constants $a=1,b=-2,c=a'-3$. Then simply check the discriminant $D=\sqrt{b^2-4ac}>0$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: It may be rewritten as $(x-1)^2+a-4=0$ or $(x-1)^2=4-a$, hence $4-a$ is positive.

Answer (score 2):

For a general quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, the roots $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are given by $$ \alpha_{1,2} = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} $$ For there to be two roots, we'd need the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ to be non-zero, otherwise there'd only be one root that's $-b/2a$.

In other words, we desire $$ (-2)^2 - 4(1)(a-3) \neq 0 \iff a \neq 4 $$

> As noted by Zain, if you're only looking for real roots, for $\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$ to be defined we desire that $$b^2 - 4ac > 0 \iff a < 4$$

Comment: I think we can deduce from the context that we're working in the real field, so $b^2 - 4ac > 0$. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> $$f(x)=x-2+\frac{a-3}{x}$$
>   $$\color{blue}{x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}$$

Distinct real solutions iff $b^2-4ac\geq0$

You should get

$$\boxed{\color{red}{x_{1,2}=1\pm\sqrt{4-a}}}$$

Comment: I think you mean "distinct real solutions" not "real solution".

Comment: I made an edit, English isn't my first language

Answer (score 1):

$x-2+\frac{a-3}{x}=0$

$x\neq0$, so

$x^2-2x+a-3=0$

$\Delta= (2)^2-4(1)(a-3)=4-4a+12=16-4a$

We have two real roots when $\Delta > 0$, that is when

$16-4a>0$, that is when $a<4$

Comment: It was only specified that there be more than one root.  Complex roots weren't ruled out at all. Also, I don't think that's correct ...

Comment: Check the arithmetic here.

Comment: I sure am stupid today. Sorry for that arithmetic mistake. And I assumed he meant real roots because he defined it as $f(x)$ not as $f(z)$. I know it doesn't matter, but OP didn't specify.

Comment: @MKF I saw your edit on this post and I rejected it because I think that you substantially changed the answer given by Hasan Saad, however, I still think that it was a very substantial and nice edit and you could post it as your own answer! :-)